# java Освобождение ресурса конструкцией try-with-resources

Tags: java, try

Нужна ваша помощь.
Класс FileReader формирует стрим из лог-файла:

```
public class FileReader {

    public Stream<String> readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        URL fileURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
        try {
            if (fileURL == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Missing file \"" + fileName + "\"");
            }
            return Files.lines(Paths.get(fileURL.toURI()));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException exception) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Missing file \"" + fileName + "\"");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как здесь применить конструкцию try-with-resources?
Так не работает, поскольку URL не реализует java.lang.AutoCloseable:

```
try (URL fileURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)) { ...
```

Comment: А не реализует URL интерфейс AutoCloseable потому, что ничего не открывает и закрывать соответственно нечего.

Comment: Сперва определитесь зачем вам это нужно? Что вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со стримами try-with-resources надо применять там, где с ними идёт работа. В вашем случае в месте вызова метода readFile:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = fileReader.readFile("some_file.txt")) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!